# Showing that a convergent sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a \in (\min_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i, \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i)$ for some $n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a real sequence $(a_n)_n$, which converges to a limit $a \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $$a \in \left(\min_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i, \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i \right)$$ for some $n$.

In other words, the sequence does not converge to either $\lim_{n \to \infty} \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i$. Or, the sequence is greater than its limit at least once and smaller than its limit at least once.

Are there any known sufficient conditions for this to hold? Clearly it is necessary (but not sufficient) that infinitely many term differences $a_n-a_{n-1}$ are negative and infinitely many are positive.

For the sake of elucidation, I'll post here the specific sequence I'm working with. Let $G \in \{2,3,\dots\}$ and $\sum_{g=1}^G \pi^{(g)} = 1$, where $0 \leq \pi^{(g)} \leq 1$ for each $g$. Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be iid random variables with categorical distribution $C(\pi^{(1)},\dots,\pi^{(g)})$. Define $n_g = \sum_{i=1}^n I(x_i = g)$ so that $n = \sum_{g =1}^G n_g$ and
\begin{equation}
\eta_{nij} = \begin{cases}
1 \mbox{ if } x_i \neq x_g \\
-\left(\frac{n-n_g}{n_g-1}\right) \mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I'm interested in the sequence given by terms of the form $$a_n = \left( \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \eta_{nij}^2 \right)^{-1} \sum_{I} \eta_{nij} \eta_{ni'j'}$$ where $I = \{ (i,j,i',j') \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}^4 \mid i,j,i',j' \text{ pairwise distinct}\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is not even necessary because $a\in[a_1,a_2]$ can be satisfied so the remaining of the $a_i$ can behave as they want.

It is also indeed not sufficient because the sequence can be "globally increasing" (i.e. $\forall A<a,\exists n_0\mid n>n_0\, a_n>A$) but yet still lower than the limit $a$.

For instance you can take $a_{2n}=1-\frac 1n$ and $a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}-\frac 1{n^2}$, there are many infinitely swaps but none of the $a_i\ge 1$.

Let assume that for some $n_1$ all $a_{i<n_1}$ are on the same side of $a$, then your result asks that there exists some $n_2$ such that $a_{n_2}$ is on the other side, just one of the infinitely many remaining.
You can see that this condition is in fact not much different from the result itself and moreover that it tells nothing about the behaviour at infinity of the sequence.

Anyway we can devise some sufficient conditions for instance that there exists adjacent subsequences, i.e one increasing subsequence $a_{\phi(i)}\nearrow$ and one decreasing subsequence $a_{\psi(i)}\searrow$ both converging to $a$, but this is quite a strong constraint.

Even more trivial if $a_{n_0}=a$ for some $n_0$ then the result is automatically satisfied, we just need one term to be equal to the limit in this case.

The result is a result on the "first" terms of the sequence, so conditions on the behaviour at infinity will most surely be extremely strong compared to a barely necessary condition.